# un recognized css declarations

Tags: html, css

I was editing a clients stylesheet today and saw this in it

```
p {
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-webkit-hyphenate-character: "\2010";
-webkit-hyphenate-limit-after: 1;
-webkit-hyphenate-limit-before: 3;
-moz-hyphens: manual;
orphans: 3;
widows: 3;
}
```

Obviously I am familiar with `-webkit` and `-moz` and I can using logic and my css understanding to figure out some of it but man is this really something that stumped me. Sure I could google it but I thought it would be best getting input from the community here. Thanks guys.

Comment: Which ones do you not understand?

Comment: I specifally have never saw `orphans: 3;`
`widows: 3;`

Comment: But still not sure that the whole div is trying to do

Comment: w3schools...Our teacher is alive still

Comment: @Deekey http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Did you try *searching* for the properties you didn't understand?  http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/widows, http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/orphans

Comment: The point was to post it here and have the community answer it. A lot of people search on here for answers and that makes it easier then going to w3schools or something similar

Comment: You're supposed to try figuring things out for yourself *first*, then ask if you get stuck.  The answer to this question was found on the first page of search results for "css windows property" and "css orphans property".

Comment: Take a peek at the [meta opinions on the matter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/33376/195481)

Comment: Yes and as quoted by LuckyLindy with 23 up-votes "Sometimes Googling something is difficult for someone who doesn't know where to start, while very easy for others. If it's not immediately apparent for what you should be searching, then I don't think it's lazy to ask here."

Comment: And the down votes keep coming....ridiculous in my opinion

Comment: Are they going to create a stack overflow "Newbie" edition for those that are not as advanced as the people down-voting a legitimate question.

Comment: I think the "Sure I could Google it..." phrase is the primary cause of the down votes, everyone on SO gives their time freely and voluntarily - some questions can take considerable time with detailed, complex answers requiring considerable research. Whilst users are willing to help, it should be assisting and not solving the whole problem - if you had searched (and there are generally excellent articles on the internet via CSS Tricks and Smashing Magazine to name but two) and then come back with any questions you still had it is likely that would have been upvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `orphan` is the first line of a paragraph that is left behind on the old page while the paragraph continues on the next.

[**orphan documentation**](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/orphans/)

A `widow` is the last line of a paragraph that is left alone on a new page or in a new column.

[**widow documentation**](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/widows/)

Comment: Thank you Brian, that is what I was looking for, for a PERSON to answer it here as apposed to someone googling or wiki'ing it to death only to get a long technical explanation that does me no good in the interim time before I do dive into one of those resources and see the full use and reason for them.

Answer (score 1):

the **hyphens** property is still a working draft .. this link will show you the browser support for it:

http://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens

> Method of controlling when words at the end of lines should be
>   hyphenated using the "hyphens" property.

**orphans** property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/orphans

**widows** property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/widows